# How to invalidate "A or B" type claim?

Tags: invalidate

I want to find a prior art document based on anticipation. Here is an example claim in two types.

Type 1: The system of claim 1, wherein the specific device is "one of A and B."
Type 2: The system of claim 1, wherein the specific device is "A or B."

If I find a Document 1 which is disclosing that "the specific device is A," could the Document be used as prior art? Or should I find a document describing exactly that "the specific device is A or B?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Type 1: The system of claim 1, wherein the specific device is "one of A and B." Type 2: The system of claim 1, wherein the specific device is "A or B."

These are equivalent.

> If I find a Document 1 which is disclosing that "the specific device is A," could the Document be used as prior art?

Yes. You only have to find *something* within the scope of the claim to render it invalid by anticipation. You don't have to show that *everything* within the scope of the claim was anticipated.

Note that, if there is anything at all special about B, it would be unusual for a patentee not to have a narrower claim that limits specifically to B. So if you are infringing by using B, you wouldn't usually escape just by finding A in the prior art.